# Sequelize Validation Error (isIn)

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

This is my model:

```js
type: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: 'text',
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          isIn: {
            args: [['text', 'numeric', 'boolean', 'enum']],
            msg: 'Must be a valid type',
          },
        },
      },
```

But it isn't validating the array and console throws me the following error:

`SequelizeValidationError: Validation error: Validation isIn on condition failed`

Sometimes can validate the array but sometimes fails.

Any ideas?

My Sequelize Version: `^4.22.6`

**EDIT:**

I'm basing in Sequelize documentation for model definition: [HERE](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html)

Specifically this code:

```js
isIn: {
  args: [['en', 'zh']],
  msg: "Must be English or Chinese"
}
```

Which is wrong with my code?

Answer (score -1):

I think you have an extra quote "," here:

```
msg: 'Must be a valid type',
```

Delete the finish quote.